# Removing Guest Session at login in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login, guest-session

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS it works fine but I want to remove the guest account login.

Comment: What made you think that lightdm is not in use in 14.04? (It is.)

Comment: @Florian Diesch,@Eric Carvalho,@Warren Hill,@Sneetsher,@Mitch,@ Gunnar Hjalmarsson - by that time when i asked this question i searched the web and found Ubuntu 14.04 LTS does not use lightdm to handle logins instead it uses Unity 8 saying its some new feature for ubuntu 14.04 LTS version (found it false later) as i am new to ubuntu that time i dont know about lightdm or login handling. So i posted a new question for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
```

Add the following line, save and then close.

```
allow-guest=false
```

Reboot, and you're set.

[image]

**Edit**

Thanks to [Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson)

Based on Gunnar Hjalmarsson comment "ubuntu-session was last updated in the middle of March. Try sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session" when that is done, the Guest session returns.

After some research, this can be done a different way as well.

Open `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file from your terminal using the following command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

If the file exists, then just add the following line:

```
allow-guest=false
```

Otherwise copy and paste the following into it:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
```

Save the file and exit the editor.  Reboot your system, and the changes will remain even after an update to ubuntu-session as mentioned by Gunnar Hjalmarsson's comment.

Comment: Thanks you. It worked. I thinks Ubuntu should have a GUI for disable/enable guest user.

Comment: `echo "allow-guest=false" |sudo tee -a /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`

Comment: Editing package files under `/usr/share` is a bad idea, since such changes get lost at upgrades. (50-ubuntu.conf belongs to package ubuntu-session.) Create a new file instead, as suggested in the answer by mnstalemate.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have edit the file and changes have not been lost, and I've done updated every time they're available.

Comment: @Mitch: ubuntu-session was last updated in the middle of March. Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session`

Comment: There's no guarantee /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf won't be overwritten on a future update. @mnstalemate's answer is the way to go: http://askubuntu.com/a/451562/3291

Comment: Confirmed working in 16.04. Just adding `allow-guest=false` to lightdm.conf did the trick.

Answer (score 38):

To remove guest login :

1. `sudo sh -c 'printf "[SeatDefaults]\nallow-guest=false\n" > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf'`
2. This will create a new file in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`
3. To get back guest login again remove `50-no-guest.conf`

To remove remote login :

1. `sudo sh -c 'printf "[SeatDefaults]\ngreeter-show-remote-login=false\n" >/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-remote-login.conf'`
2. This will create a new file in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`
3. To get back remote login again remove `50-no-remote-login.conf`

Comment: This is the best method and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: best answer imho - remind me to scroll down first in the future

Comment: @Cookie: Or checking the [official docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html) first. ;)

Comment: This is a good answer, however I would recommend editing the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-new-guest.conf` instead. `/usr/share` is reserved for files installed with the package manager, `/etc` is expected to be edited by sysadmins. LightDM configuration in `/etc` also takes precedence over configuration in `/usr`.

Answer (score 0):

Or just add:

`greeter-show-remote-login=false`

to `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`

along with your `disable guest line`

No need to overcomplicate a very simple fix by creating additional config files besides default, which will inevidably only confuse the OS at some point when the two files conflict, or the default file is erased and one of your two 'fixes' gets undone because you didn't do them together.

Comment: Can you also include the disable guest line?

Comment: You are wrong. Creating additional config files is the way to go. Editing a package owned file under `/usr/share` will only work until next time the package is upgraded.

Comment: Agree that multiple config files are the way to go, as it is more extensible and causes less conflicts... also easier to automate with devops scripts!