# Disabled guest losgin - I cant boot now

Tags: lenovo

I was looking to disable guest login and I found one link 'remove guest login ubuntu' http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-disable-guest-account-in-ubuntu-12-04precise.html

I did this:
Open /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file

from your terminal using the following command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line

```
allow-guest=false
```

Save and exit the file

After I restarted my laptop I see "The system is running in low-graphics mode"

[image]

My question is: How can i fix this problem? should i re-install ubuntu?

Comment: The obvious thing to ask is "did you undo the change you did and see if it went back to what it was"?

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing Guest Session at login in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451526/removing-guest-session-at-login-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` had some configuration in it. This is not longer true in Ubuntu 14.04. Old guides assumed the presence of some configuration in it. Now you need to add a `SeatDefaults` section if you wish to use that method:

```
[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=false
```

Comment: I cant open terminal, i started in recovery mode and i click in "ROOT" but when i try to undo those changes but i see "Cannot open display"

Comment: Use a TTY and a command line editor. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1.

Comment: CTRL-ALT-F1  never worked for me, i dont know why... Can i use LIVEUSB to edit this file again? or i must install ubuntu again?

Comment: @thumper2 Live usb should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file back to the way it was by booting from an Ubuntu Live CD (or live flash drive) and then browsing your drive in Nautilus (file manager) to mount it and then edit it with `gksudo gedit /media/(drive name here)/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.