# Turn off or disable the guest account in kUbuntu using KDE system settings GUI

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde

How do I turn off or disable the guest account in kUbuntu using the KDE GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to: System Settings
2. On the bottom under "System Administration" click "Login Screen (LightDM)"
3. Click the "General" tab
4. Uncheck "Allow guest login"
5. Click "Apply"

Note: The following are good related post on turning off or disabling guest accounts:

[How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)
[Removing Guest Session at login in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451526/removing-guest-session-at-login-in-ubuntu-14-04)